# Block a channel that subscribed to my channel

Tags: youtube

I recently was notified that some channel (not user) subscribed to my youtube channel.

I want to block this channel because I believe it is a troll.  However, I can't find a way to do this.

I found a lot of links that explain how to block a user, but not a channel.

Answer (score 1):

The channel is the user. They are the same. If you go to the channel, and click the little arrow/gear in the top right, you can block them.

Also, you should try blocking the Google+ user/page associated with the youtube account.

Comment: You might want to add this will only block direct communication with the user.  This "troll" will still be able to post comments to the user's video.

Comment: Really? I thought the block function was implemented for just this reason. How about if the user blocks the g+ page linked to the channel? With the new comment section this should work.

Comment: The only arrow/gear thing in the top right is next to my picture.  I did go to the channel, hit the about link, then blocked from there.  Is that good enough?  I still see a subscription from this channel...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot block someone from subscribing or from viewing your channel, simply because it gives you a false sense of security: The person stalking you can simply log out, or use the (anonymous) RSS feed to subscribe to your channel, and you have no way of knowing or preventing this.

If you aren't comfortable with anyone viewing your video, do upload them as private, or upload them on a platform that isn't a public video platform – facebook video and Google Photos come to mind.